# Which software allows calculating volume between multivariate polynomial boundaries

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, reference-request, definite-integrals, numerical-methods

I want to calculate the volume of the set of triples $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3$ with

$$0<z<1,$$
$$3z<y<1+2z,$$
$$2y-3z<x<1+y-z,$$

and most importantly

$$18xyz-4x^3z+x^2y^2-4y^3-27z^2>0.$$

I have tried to calculate the volume analytically, but this is obviously quite tricky to say the least. I could get an estimate using monte carlo methods, but I would like an exact answer if possible.

It would be even better if, for fixed $x\in(0,3)$, there was also a closed formula for the surface area of the set of all $(y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ that obey all the inequalities, but I would not be surprised if this is not feasible.

I have tried looking up how I can calculate this with Wolfram Alpha, but I was unable to find any useful references.